# Deploying Multiple Microservices in different repositories to a single VM using bitbucket pipelines and docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, google-compute-engine, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a total of 8 Nodejs services in 8 different repositories on bitbucket. The services share some common code which is present in another repository called Brain. I want to create bitbucket pipelines in all of these repositories so that I can do the following things:

1. Build the docker image for each service and store it in Google Container Registry
2. Use ssh-run or a similar runner to ssh into my GCE VM and run a docker-compose pull and docker-compose up to deploy the latest versions.
3. Perform zero downtime update, i.e, keep the old containers running until the new containers are ready.

What would be the best way of doing this? Currently I'm facing the following problems:

1. When I push changes to the Brain repository, I need to build images for all the different services. Most of the time I'm pushing both to my brain repository and some other service repository. So multiple images are being built.
2. When I push changes to the Brain repository, as I build the different images for the services, all of them try to deploy using ssh-run. I don't know if this is sustainable and may crash my VM?

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you think the VM might crash? Your question has no details on what is deployed in the VM, so we have no idea of its architecture or durability. I also think your question is too broad and unfocused. What is the single problem you are trying to solve? If you have multiple issues, create multiple posts.

Comment: "Perform zero downtime update, i.e, keep the old containers running until the new containers are ready."
You want/need docker swarm mode, not docker compose, for this.

Comment: Kubernetes (GKE) could also do zero-downtime updates, though its deployment model is much more complex than Compose.  You intrinsically will have to rebuild all of your images when you change the shared code.